# How to make Google Chrome spacebar scrolling smooth on OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, scrolling

I'm a recent OS X convert and I would like to scroll pages in Google Chrome using the spacebar. However, currently spacebar scrolling in Google Chrome is simply jumping from one section of the page to the next, which makes it difficult to keep track with your eyes.

Is there anyway to make Google Chrome on OS X scroll smoothly with the spacebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this extension which solves the problem perfectly for me:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn?hl=en

Comment: Actually, this introduces a problem on OS X's Chrome I think. It hinders the two finger swipe right and left for page back and forward.